# EditText hint doesn't show

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext, hint

My `EditText` configured as follows won't show the hint:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="The hint..."
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

It works if I set `android:gravity="left"` or if I remove `android:scrollHorizontally` and `android:singleLine` attributes, which is not desirable. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm that `editText` is not displaying the hint when `gravity` is `center` or `right` and `singleLine` is set.  I am also looking for a solution.

Comment: I can no longer edit my last comment, but I wanted to mention that this is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252

Answer (score 73):

using `android:ellipsize="end"` fixed it for me
Weird bug !! (but Android has a lot of these weirdo bug)

Comment: after added this TAG I can see hint in Emulator but still no luck with Real Device (i.e. sony ericsson xperia )

Comment: "android:ellipsize" property works for me..  strange...!

Answer (score 58):

In Lollipop version the default text and hint text color is white for `EditText`.
So we have to change like this in `EditText`

```
android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Strange behavior. Only one of my apps had this problem, but solved by this. Wonder what's really going on behind.

Answer (score 17):

I wanted my single-line `EditText` box to scroll but keep the hint on the right also.
I had the same issue and got the hint to stick by keeping `gravity="right"`, and setting `singleLine="true"` and `ellipsize="end"`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to give text color to hint

```
android:textColorHint="#000000"
```

Comment: That's not enough for Android 2.3 (I tested on HTS Desire S). Also should add android:ellipsize="end".

Answer (score 2):

No need of `android:scrollHorizontally` attribute. Remove it.`EditText` is a fixed item on the screen. we want scroll the layout contains the EditText is enough. that is the best design too.  you have put `android:ellipsize="end"` instead of `android:scrollHorizontally`.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. If you read documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_scrollHorizontally, when the text you type doesn't fit into the field, android:scrollHorizontally attribute allows the text to scroll within the field (no scroll bars of course). It has nothing to do with the layout scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Using android:ellipsize="end" resolves the obvious platform bug. Unfortunately, Xperias still misbehave :(

I found no other solution than to:

```
if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.matches(".*[Ss]ony.*"))
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
else
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the hint text color, sometimes the hint color is the same as the background color

```
android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome!
It seems like this answer is basically a repeat of a couple others-

Answer (score 1):

This is how, I did for by `EditText` to have hint in it.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/productQuantity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/quantity"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>
```

[image: Screenshot of what the above code should look like]

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UserText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/UserPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/UserHint"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/UserName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the style to `"@style/Base.WidgetMaterialComponents.TextImputEditText"`. For me it wasn't gravity or color.

Answer (score 0):

In my android studio is dolphin(old version) and I have set compileSdkVersion 33 so this issue come then i **compileSdkVersion 32 set**. It's working fine. So decrease compileSdkVersion version.
[image]