# Hint Not Displaying When numeric="integer" in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

The title is the question.

Anybody know any solution?

Please help me.

---

Shaiful

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608234/edittext-hint-doesnt-show

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The XML attribute android:numeric is not a boolean value and "true" is not a valid parameter, it must be one ore more of "integer", "signed", "decimal".

Per the sample you've posted, your issue is due to the choice of adding gravity to center the text.  There is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13895) in the SDK that, as of 2.3, it looks like is still not fixed.  This bug hides the hint text when `android:singleLine` and any custom value of `android:gravity` are set together.  Your choice at this juncture really is to remove one or the other.  Some workaround options:

1. Remove the `android:gravity` declaration and have the text left-aligned.
2. Keep the declaration and remove android:singleLine.  In this case, you will probably have to override the Editor Action in order to get the default Next or Done button on the soft keypad.
3. Remove `android:gravity`, and set `layout_width="wrap_content"`.  Then appropriately center the entire widget in the parent layout.  This may look a little goofy with the standard `EditText` background as it will grow and shrink.  You may have to set this to null and make the background part of a parent container.

Also, don't forget to star the bug :)

Cheers.

Comment: My mistake. I actually used numeric="integer". And no hint. :(

Comment: I reiterate.  Please post some code that we can look at to assis you further.

Comment: `<EditText android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"` `android:phoneNumber="true"` `android:singleLine="true" ``android:gravity="center_horizontal" ``android:layout_width="fill_parent" ``android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use one of the attributes specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3anumeric) for the numeric attribute. Not sure if it solves the problem but you should use one of those values as it states: *"Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values."*

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue myself and none of the posts I found here could help me out.

Then when I was fiddeling with the EditText again, I found out that the hint does show when an **android:inputType** was assigned in combination with **android:ellipsize**.

A later search pointed into the same direction: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252

Still it's a weird issue, which should already be fixed...