# How to implement an EditText with Hint = String type and IME keyboard(android:inputType) = number?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I have an EditText which has a hint field saying "Please enter a number". The IME keyboard that I want is that of type number ie. only numbers are allowed!

The problem is if I use the following in the xml layout :

```
<EditText>
...
android:inputType="number"
android:hint="Please Enter a 10 digit number"
</EditText>
```

the hint will not be displayed as only numbers are allowed in the EditText.

How to implement a solution that has both :
1. A hint in words/string
2. Input allowed type(IME keyboard) of type number ?

**EDIT**

Yes, I am using gravity and singleLine attributes and by seeing the comments I guess its because of a known bug in the SDK. I was testing it on 2.3 ver phone.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945311/645270) (or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8156924/645270)) your problem? (Bug with gravity and hints)

Answer (score 2):

Check the syntax. It works for both..

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/ed"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:hint="Please Enter a 10 digit number"/>
```