# EditText hint issues

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know there is alot of well reported issues with EditText Hint  [not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608234/edittext-hint-doesnt-show%20showing), but my issue is a little diferent, when i try to show an hint in and EditTExt center aligned (gravity="center") it aligns to the left with the first character "eatten" on at least an LG-E610 running Android 4.0.3 (15), it shows fine on my S4 running 4.4.2.

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_username" />
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it's working properly in my case. clean your project and then try again.

Comment: Not working in an LG-E610

Comment: Its working fine.Uninstall your application from your device then install it again.

Comment: It's not, at least on the LG-E610, the screenshot i gave is from a project done from scratch.

Comment: If you don't set the gravity, does the hint show normally?

Comment: If i set the gravity to center on the LG-E610 (at least) it alligns to the left and "eats" the first hint character, if don't set the gravity it showsjust fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't end up finding a solution for this and just gave up on using gravity center on the EditTExt