# Android - EditText not showing any text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I seem to have quite a specific problem. I have two tablets, one runs on Android 6.0.1, the other on 5.1.1.
I have an activity and a fragment (the fragment is located on an activity). Each has an EditText element with the following layout:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etInputForm_1_1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvDescription_1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

The problem is, if I test it on the device with Android 6.0.1, everything seems to be ok, I can input text wherever I want to, however on the device with 5.1.1, the EditText in the fragment always seems to be empty no matter how many letters I type (the EditText in the activity still works fine).

But the logs still show that the text IS there (however we can't see it).
Anyone had similar problem and a solution to this?

Comment: do you use the same background color?

Comment: try android:textColorHint="#000000". Its a "bug" even if you dont use hints. It may help. Try android:ellipsize="end" aswell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608234/edittext-hint-doesnt-show). Anyway, in your case it seems to be another issue. Please post the parent Layout aswell

Comment: The background color is another. This problem exists on android 5.1.1, on the higher versions it seems to work fine.

Comment: Switching textColorHelp not helping either and so is ellipsize.
The parent layout is just as simple as this:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentRegistrationLogin"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Seems that the support fragment class is buggy when using on tablets with Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue where the edit text hint wouldn't go away (representing text was in the field) and no text would show up when I was typing but my logs showed text was indeed in the field. I also had an issue where my spinners would not show the selected option

I solved it by enabling hardware acceleration for my application. Since it is enabled by default (I believe) I removed this line from my `<application></application>` section of my manifest file: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

Comment: I'm baffled at how hardware acceleration could possible effect this

Answer (score 0):

My issue resolved after removing following line from edit text.

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```